# Django - Paython: TypeError at /news news() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dbemail'

Tags: python, django

Here is my model:

```
class news(models.Model):
    dbemail = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dbsubject = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    dbdetail = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    dbimage = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dbdatetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return "Email: " + self.dbemail + " | Subject: " + self.dbsubject + " | datetime: " + self.dbdatetime
```

Here is a function in my view that is responsible for handling post method for the news:

```
def news(request):
    if 'email' in request.session:
        email = request.session['email']
        if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['newsimage']:
            myfile = request.FILES['newsimage']
            fs = FileSystemStorage(location='newsimages/')
            filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
            uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)

            newsinfo = newsForm(request.POST)
            if newsinfo.is_valid():
                subject = newsinfo.cleaned_data['subject']
                detail = newsinfo.cleaned_data['detail']
                newsData = news(dbemail = email, dbsubject = subject, dbdetail = detail, dbimage = uploaded_file_url)
                newsData.save()
                message = "News has been added"
                form = newsForm()
                return render(request, 'news.html', {
                    'myform': form,
                    'message': message
                })

        else:
            form = newsForm()
            return render(request, 'news.html', {'myform': form})
    else:
        request.session['profileError'] = "You have to sign up or log in first!"
        return redirect('login')
```

Error is on this line:

```
newsData = news(dbemail = email, dbsubject = subject, dbdetail = detail, dbimage = uploaded_file_url)
```

This is the error detail:

```
TypeError at /news
news() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dbemail'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/news
Django Version: 4.2.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
news() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dbemail'
Exception Location: C:\Users\farib\Desktop\Python\finalproject\main\views.py, line 105, in news
Raised during:  main.views.news
```

I have the news model imported in views.py so there is no problem of recognizing it but it cannot recognize dbemail! why is that? Do you have any idea?

I was expecting the data to be saved on the model and I can see it in the database but it does not work. I do not know why! I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model and the view function have the same name, so with `news`, you call the view function. Normally class names are written in *PascalCase* which will avoid collisions, so:

```
class News(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Email: {self.email} | Subject: {self.subject} | datetime: {self.datetime}'
```

If you use a `ModelForm`, you can just save that form, so:

```
from django import forms


class NewsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = ('subject', 'detail')
```

then you can save this in the view with:

```
def news(request):
    # …
    form = newsForm(request.POST)
    if newsinfo.is_valid():
        form.instance.email = email
        form.instance.image = uploaded_file_url
        form.save()
        return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Comment: Teach me how you respond so quickly with the detailed answer :) I wanna be your student hehe.

Answer (score 2):

most certainly you have a name conflict between your model `news` and the function based view `news`.

I would recommend to rename the model to `News` and rename the view to something like news_add(..)

Comment: Thank you very much. I could not see the problem myself. Thank you. Thank you.